# How to implement template file that would reside in database?

Tags: 8, theming

I was wondering if it would be possible to have a template "file" that would be stored only in DB and would not exist physically?

Twig tempaltes are parsed from files only once and they are processed and stored in DB anyway so would it be possible to have such DB entry from the get-go?

Comment: Since the processed files are already stored in the database, what is the point to store a template file in the database? Drupal 8 is going in the direction opposite with the configuration data because a database cannot be versioned.

Comment: I have case where this would be a good solution but it interests me more out of a curiosity than necessity.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that twig templates are stored in the DB? They are not. They're stored as php files in the php storage.

Comment: I am not saying they are stored in DB, I am saying they are cached in DB so the files are not touched after that.

Comment: No, they are not. As I said, they're cached as PHP files in php storage.

Comment: OK, and so would it be possible to "inject" via some hook a "fake" template into the template discovery process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a loader, see `Drupal\Core\Template\Loader` for the implementations that drupal core uses and their parent classes/interfaces.

See also how they're registered in core.services.yml, for example:

```
twig.loader.filesystem:
    class: Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\FilesystemLoader
    arguments: ['@app.root', '@module_handler', '@theme_handler']
    tags:
      - { name: twig.loader, priority: 100 }
```

So, it's certainly possible to do it, if it's a good idea is another question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Berdir suggestion I have created my implementation like this(just finished so probably som fine-tuning will take place):

```
/**
 * Twig loader that uses the database as backend for templates.
 */
class DatabaseLoader implements \Twig_LoaderInterface {

  /**
   * The name of the template collection in the backend storage.
   */
  CONST COLLECTION = 'twig_templates';

  /**
   * The key value backend service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\KeyValueStore\KeyValueStoreInterface
   */
  protected $key_value;

  /**
   * The list of all templates stored in the database backend
   * for the currently active theme. Each key is the template name
   * and each value is the UNIX timestamp of last change made to the template.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected static $registry = NULL;

  /**
   * Static cache for loaded templates keyed by their name.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected static $templates = [];

  /**
   * Constructs a new DatabaseLoader object.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\KeyValueStore\KeyValueFactoryInterface $key_value
   *   The key_value storage backend service.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Extension\ThemeHandlerInterface $theme_handler
   *   The theme handler service.
   */
  public function __construct(KeyValueFactoryInterface $key_value, ThemeHandlerInterface $theme_handler) {
    $this->key_value = $key_value->get(static::COLLECTION);
    $this->theme = $theme_handler->getDefault();
    $this->registryLoad();
  }

  /**
   * Helper method to load the registry from the storage.
   */
  protected function registryLoad() {
    if (is_null(static::$registry)) {
      static::$registry = $this->key_value->get('registry_' . $this->theme, []);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Helper method to write registry into the storage.
   */
  protected function registryUpdate() {
    $this->key_value->set('registry_' . $this->theme, static::$registry);
  }

  /**
   * Helper method to flush the registry.
   * This method is called when the site cache is being flushed
   * and it will set timestamps for all templates to current time
   * so all templates will indicate they need to be rebuilt.
   *
   * @see foo_rebuild()
   */
  public function registryRebuild() {
    static::$registry = array_fill_keys(array_keys(static::$registry), REQUEST_TIME);
    $this->registryUpdate();
  }

  /**
   * Helper method to normalize the template name.
   * For example "profiles/foo/themes/bar/templates/system/html.html.twig"
   * will get transformed into "html".
   *
   * @param string $name
   *   The full template name.
   *
   * @return string
   *   Normalized template name.
   *
   * @throws \Twig_Error_Loader
   *   If inline template is provided.
   */
  public function normalize($name) {
    if (stripos($name, '{') !== FALSE) {
      throw new \Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Template "%s" is not defined.', $name));
    }

    $split = explode('/', $name);
    return explode('.', end($split))[0];
  }

  /**
   * Helper method to get the storage key for provided template.
   *
   * @param string $name
   *   The template name.
   *
   * @return string
   *   The key-value storage collection key for the provided template.
   */
  protected function getKey($name) {
    return $this->theme . '.' . $name;
  }

  /**
   * Upserts a template into the storage.
   *
   * @param string $name
   *   The template name.
   * @param string $template
   *   The content of the template.
   */
  public function saveTemplate($name, $template) {
    $this->key_value->set($this->getKey($name), $template);
    static::$templates[$name] = $template;

    static::$registry[$name] = time();
    $this->registryUpdate();
  }

  /**
   * Deletes provided template.
   *
   * @param string $name
   *   Template name.
   */
  public function deleteTemplate($name) {
    if (isset(static::$registry[$name])) {
      $this->key_value->delete($this->getKey($name));
      unset(static::$templates[$name]);

      unset(static::$registry[$name]);
      $this->registryUpdate();
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getSource($name) {
    $name = $this->normalize($name);

    if (isset(static::$registry[$name])) {
      if (!isset(static::$templates[$name])) {
        static::$templates[$name] = $this->key_value->get($this->getKey($name), '');
      }
      return static::$templates[$name];
    } else {
      throw new \Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Template "%s" is not defined.', $name));
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheKey($name) {
    $name = $this->normalize($name);

    if (isset(static::$registry[$name])) {
      return $name;
    } else {
      throw new \Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Template "%s" is not defined.', $name));
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function isFresh($name, $time) {
    $name = $this->normalize($name);

    if (isset(static::$registry[$name])) {
      return static::$registry[$name] <= $time;
    } else {
      throw new \Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Template "%s" is not defined.', $name));
    }
  }

}
```

The service:

```
foo_twig_db_loader:
    class: Drupal\foo\Template\Loader\DatabaseLoader
    arguments: ['@keyvalue', '@theme_handler']
    tags:
      - { name: twig.loader, priority: 101 }
```

The module file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_rebuild().
 */
function foo_rebuild() {
  \Drupal::service('foo_twig_db_loader')->registryRebuild();
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Merqio/TwigDbLoader